# Azure Container Level Access

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have recruitment that need to store the file in Blob Storage. The blob storage account which i have created for a company. There are multiple site for a same company. We need to restrict the site member to see other site files. So I need the access key based on container level.

The container will be created dynamically from C#. The credential / access key that should be created while creating the container from C# and the container level access key / credential will be shared with site members not the storage account access key. Storage account key will be in application configure side. So storage account key will be hidden from the site members.

How do I get the container level access key / credential in Azure blob storage?

Comment: There is access no such access key at the container level, as @GeorgeChen said, you shoould use SAS Token or RBAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#what-is-a-shared-access-signature) could meet your requirements.With a SAS, you can grant clients access to resources in your storage account, without sharing your account keys. And you could set the interval over which the SAS is valid and the permissions granted by the SAS. For example, a SAS for a blob might grant read and write permissions to that blob, but not delete permissions.

You could create `SAS` pointing to one or more resources and including a token that contains a special set of query parameters.

Here are two examples about how to use SAS, [first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#sas-examples) SAS examples and [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2) SAS.

If you still have other questions, please me know.

Comment: Thanks you :-) I will try to use SAS and get back to you.

Comment: @Guruprakash C if my answer works, you could mark my answer.Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :-) @George Chen